# Do seaching in excel on typing

Tags: vba, excel

I am dealing with data input. Every time before I input one record, I need to search and locate one cell in about 5000 rows. I am thinking if it is possible to do the search while typing instead of using the search function in excel. My idea is to capture the keypress event of a spreadsheet, if it is a character (letter 'A' to 'Z' or 'a' to 'z'), append it to a string called searchVal do the search immediate with a function. When the user press ESC, it will clean up the searchVal. First of all, I got the following code from online, trying to capture the ESC keydown

```
Private searchVal As String


Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "ESC", "CleanSearchKey"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "ESC"
End Sub

Sub CleanSearchKey()
  searchVal = ""
  MsgBox "CleanSearchKey"
End Sub
```

But his code doesn't work, it seems that the CleanSearchKey never triggered. As for capturing the key down for 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z', I don't want know how to capture it in a sheet so I add an inputbox on sheet1, assigned the following macro to the inputbox

```
Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  If (KeyAscii >= 65 And KeyAscii <= 90) Or (KeyAscii >= 97 And KeyAscii <= 122) Then
    searchVal = searchVal & KeyAscii
  Else
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If

End Sub
```

But it then said "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". So what is the right way to capture the key on a sheet? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you need this custom 'search while writing' option? I would rather use Excel's autofilter, which does the searching you describe in 2007 and higher, or let a macro find the values for you in a worksheet's `Change` event. If you really wanted to do what you described I'd load the values in a userform's list and filter on that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As stated in the beginning, I have so many data to input to the spreadsheet. For each data, I need to search in column A to locate the cell and then input the data into B column but in the same row. The data I input is given by other at a time so there is no way to filter out the row in advance. Now I use the find function in the excel, find the cell and input the number. Then run the find again to search the next one. It works but slow since I have to use the shortcut to call the find, delete the history, input the new search value and press "find next"

Comment: And is there some correlation with the input and the original data? Or more simply - how do you know what to search for when doing the input?

Comment: ok, the data is read by other person. He will tell me the data to search and the value to input each time. Once I finish inputting one data, he will read the other one and repeat the whole process until all couple thousand data finish.

Comment: Sounds rather complicated. If the search value matches exactly and only once, I would just keep writing the values down in a separate spreadsheet and `VLOOKUP` them in or run a macro to load them in the end.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work well. Since I need to update the value after the searching before I start the next data handle. Anyway, what I need is to capture the keypress on a sheet and to trigger the search function to locate the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you added for a TextBox is only applicable to a TextBox which appears on a `UserForm` object. I don't think text boxes on worksheets respond to events like `KeyPress`.

That said, you could easily configure a  simple userform to do this.

[image]

[image]

I modified your code a little bit.  I think this should get you started.  In a normal code module, do a procedure like this which will launch the UserForm. This will allow you to show the form from the Macros ribbon menu. Otherwise, you will have to invoke it manually from the Immediate Window or by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> in the VBE.

```
Sub ShowForm()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Create a UserForm, and add a textbox. Its default name should be `TextBox1`, if it is not, then make sure to change it.  In the userForm's code module, do this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim searchVal As String
Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

  searchVal = TextBox1.Value

  If (KeyAscii >= 65 And KeyAscii <= 90) Or (KeyAscii >= 97 And KeyAscii <= 122) Then
    searchVal = searchVal & Chr(KeyAscii)
    TextBox1.Value = searchVal
    Call FindValue

  End If
  If KeyAscii = 27 Then 'ESC
    searchVal = vbNullString
    TextBox1.Value = vbNullString

  Else:
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If

End Sub
Sub FindValue()
Dim rngFound as Range

    With ActiveSheet
        set rngFound = .Cells.Find(searchVal)
    End With
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox searchVal & " not found!"
    Else
        MsgBox searchVal & " found at " & rngFound.Address
    End If
End Sub
```